# How to test symfony authentication using shared context firewall?

Tags: php, security, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

I'm trying to test an application (symfony 2.6 + phpunit) that is using shared firewall by context but it is not working.
I followed documentation from http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/simulating_authentication.html

The problem is that my test is returning an anonymous token instead of UsernamePasswordToken. Why ??

This is my security.yml file

```
// app/config/security.yml
security:
    encoders:
        Marcoshoya\MarquejogoBundle\Entity\AdmUser:
            algorithm:        sha1
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations:       1

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

    providers:
        customer:
            entity: { class: MarcoshoyaMarquejogoBundle:Customer, property: email }

    firewalls:
        site:
            context: website
            pattern: ^/(?!(cliente)).*$
            anonymous: true

        customer:
            anonymous: ~
            context: website
            pattern:    ^/cliente/.*
            form_login:
                provider: customer
                check_path: /cliente/login_check
                login_path: /cliente/login
                default_target_path: /cliente

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/cliente/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/cliente, roles: [ROLE_CUSTOMER] }
```

My test file:

```
// ControllerTest.php
public function logIn()
{
    // this function is implemented as documentation
}

public function testDashboard()
{
    $this->logIn();
    $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/cliente/');

    //
    var_dump($this->client->getContainer()->get('security.context')->getToken());

}
```

Dump with problem:

```
.object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AnonymousToken)#5855 (5) {
  ["key":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AnonymousToken":private]=>
  string(13) "54b43b41cbe2a"
  ["user":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken":private]=>
  string(5) "anon."
  ["roles":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["authenticated":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken":private]=>
  bool(true)
  ["attributes":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Removing option "context" from security.yml file, I had the response that I expected:

```
.object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken)#882 (6) {
  ["credentials":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken":private]=>
  NULL
  ["providerKey":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken":private]=>
  string(8) "customer"
  ["user":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken":private]=>
  string(8) "customer"
  ["roles":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken":private]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role)#823 (1) {
      ["role":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role":private]=>
      string(13) "ROLE_CUSTOMER"
    }
  }
  ["authenticated":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken":private]=>
  bool(true)
  ["attributes":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Finally I've found the solution. Take a look at https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/11836